# Dynamically add and remove directives from element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have one select and one input text element. Depending on selected option I need to add or remove directives from input text element.

Is it possible to do it in some defined function like on ng-change in select element, like this:
 `ng-change = changeInputValidation()` ?

And if it is possible how to do that?

Comment: you could `ng-if` to add and remove directive element from DOM

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that is something like this inside a new directive:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div id="abc" blue-text>Abc</div>
    <br/>
    <button remove-blue-text="abc">Remove Directive</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('blueText', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.css('background', 'blue');
        }
    };
});

app.directive('removeBlueText', function ($compile) {
    return {
        scope: {
            idToRemove: "@removeBlueText"
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on('click', function () {
                var elem = angular.element(document.getElementById(scope.idToRemove));
                var newHtml = '<div id="abc">Abc</div>';
                $compile(newHtml)(scope, function (el) {
                    elem.replaceWith(el);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4pfbb1ds/).

Comment: As you are removing directive  van you also add the same..?

Comment: I am AngularJS beginner and this seems confusing to me. I need to add or remove particular directives from some input element when select option is changed. So, WHEN SELECT OPTION IS CHANGED, how to implement that and to integrate one part of code that you wrote?

Comment: @Ved - I removed the directive and added the same element without the directive. You can check the fiddle and see.

Comment: @bambiinela - My answer is for advanced users. I've created a new directive on an element(a button). When you click on that element it replaces an element with a new compiled element that doesn't have the directive.

Comment: @AmirPopovich I mean can you add the directive blue-text after removing it.?

Comment: @Ved - You can, simply add a new button with a new directive that does something similar with a different template(that will include the directive).